# ListView ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contextmenu

I'm having a problem with a ContextMenu.
The Activity has a ListView. By tapping and holding at an item in that ListView a ContextMenu should appear with Items "Delete" and "Push".
That's the code I use:

```
registerForContextMenu(list);
```

Works great so far.

The problem is, when I hit the "Settings-Button" on my S3, the ContextMenu also appears. Which in that case makes no sense, because no item of the ListView is selected. Is it possible to suppress that? (I don't need a ContextMenu for the whole Activity, only for the ListView's items.)

Thanks,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

You should check `menuInfo` and decide whether it is created for an item in your list, or it is an arbitrary creation what you talked about, or you can check `view1`:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view1,
                            ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view1, menuInfo);
    if(manuInfo is something){   // bla bla  or you can check view1
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

That should work, lemme know if does not.

Comment: Thanks. I did the following: `if(view1 == list) {...}` . But it still doesn't work. The ContextMenu still appears by hitting the "Settings-Button". By debugging I saw, that onCreateContextMenu() isn't even invoked after hitting that button.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

By hitting the "Settings-Button" on my S3 not onCreateContextMenu(), but onCreateOptionsMenu() is invoked where it sayed: `getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.myActivity, menu);`.
After removing that line, everything works fine.